# Apply a customized function to multiple regions in Google Earth Engine Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to extract the average last day of snow across a number of watersheds. The majority of the code has been provided here (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/identifying-first-day-no-snow) but I just can't figure out how to apply the customized function inside ee.image.reduceRegions for a FeatureCollection (let's call it Watersheds).

Provided code

```
// Define an AOI.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(-94.242, 65.79).buffer(1e4);
Map.addLayer(aoi, null, 'Area of interest');

// Calculate annual mean DOY of AOI.
var annualAoiMean = annualCol.select('calDoy').map(function(img) {
  var summary = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 1e3,
    bestEffort: true,
    maxPixels: 1e14,
    tileScale: 4,
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, summary).set('year', img.get('year'));
});
```

With the following modifications, I would get the average value for ALL the watersheds but I want the average value for each individual watershed.

```
// Calculate annual mean DOY of AOI.
var annualAoiMean = annualCol.select('calDoy').map(function(img) {
  var summary = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: Watersheds,
    scale: 1e3,
    bestEffort: true,
    maxPixels: 1e14,
    tileScale: 4,
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, summary).set('year', img.get('year'));
});
```